# How to try reusable django apps that don't provide templates inside?

Tags: django, documentation, django-templates, code-reuse

Many of the reusable django apps don't include default templates inside. James Bennett says in his presentation [Reusable Apps](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-S0tqpPga4) that providing truly portable default templates is very hard. He adds that most of the bug reports in the first release of his `registration` app were related to default templates.

This is a valid point. But without any default templates, it is very difficult to understand how an app can be reused, because the programmer can't see the reusable app in action.

What do you suggest to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 8):

Screenshots, demonstrative videos, and online demos.

It's hard to fully develop people's understand for and anticipation of a reusable app, especially enough to allow them to assess if it will work for their needs, without requiring them to read through a couple pages of documentation and spend quite a bit of time setting up and configuring the app for themselves.

Using some form of visual media allows the concepts to be relayed much quicker than documentation ever could.  If you've ever browsed for javascript widgets, you'll notice almost every author sets up a live demo.  It's because really without seeing a component someone has available, it's hard to determine if it works for you.

With Django re-usable apps it's even harder as often times you may not have the facilities to host something for everyone to use publically.  This is where screenshots or a simple video demonstrating how it works can be just as effective.

Comment: That's true. Actually, I think being able to touch and use the app is the best learning experience as it is the case with javascript widgets. The programmer sees the app in action.

Comment: +1 for online demos - it's far too much of a pain to set it up in your local dev environment only to find it does nothing like what you need.

Comment: +1. Documentation can be more than text. Demos are good.